# Malloc 2d array is always NULL

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have been trying to dynamically allocate memory for structures. I keep on getting seg faults and I am not sure why. I reduced the code to a practice program to try and figure out whats wrong. This code compiles correctly with no errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int id;
  }person;

person **new;

int main()
{
  int x, size;
  printf("How big is this? ");
  scanf("%d", &size);
  getchar();
  if((person **)malloc(size*sizeof(person))==NULL);
     {
     printf("There was a problem\n");
     exit(1);
     }
  person **new=(person **)malloc(size*sizeof(person **));
    for(x=0; x<size ;x++)
        {
        new[x]=(person *)malloc(sizeof(person *));
        new[x]->id=x*5;
        }
    for(x=0; x<size; x++)
        {
        printf("%d\t", new[x]->id);
        free(new[x]);
        }
  free(new);
  return 0;
  }
```

But whenever I try to run the program it always triggers the if statement that checks for a NULL and exits. Whenever I take out the if statement it runs perfectly and gives me the right answer. So I am not really sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end: `if((person **)malloc(size*sizeof(person))==NULL);`

Comment: Additionally, check if `scanf` succeeded, `size` may be unspecified (e.g. 0). And the first `malloc` call is a memory leak (as every `malloc` call where the result isn't assigned to anything). Check `new` for not being `NULL`. Compiler warnings could have helped with the `;` typo.

Comment: Also, don't use `malloc` without storing the return value - you won't be able to access the allocated memory. Instead, check `new == NULL` after `malloc`ing to it. (This will also make for tidier syntax in my opinion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following line has two issues:

```
if((person **)malloc(size*sizeof(person))==NULL);
```

`Issue1:` Memory leak

`Issue2:` Has `;` at the end of `if` condition.

To fix these issues use:

```
person **new=(person **)malloc(size*sizeof(person *));
if(NULL == new)
{
     printf("There was a problem\n");
     exit(1);
}
```

Also as mentioned by **francis** you need to change your `new[x]` malloc statement:

```
new[x]=(person *)malloc(sizeof(person *));
```

**To:**

```
new[x]=(person *)malloc(sizeof(person));
```

Comment: You want `sizeof(person *)`, i.e. `sizeof(*new)`, don't you?

Comment: @Oehm is right. And is also true for `new[x]=(person *)malloc(sizeof(person *));`. It should be `new[x]=(person *)malloc(sizeof(person ));` A wrong size may trigger a segmentation fault.

Comment: Everything is fine except of the memory leak one. Where is memory leak?

Comment: In this line `if((person **)malloc(size*sizeof(person))==NULL);`  .Here memory allocated by `malloc` not get freed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. I can not believe I left the semi colon on the if statement. . . Can you explain why I needed to change the pointers on malloc though? specifically the line " person **new=(person **)malloc(size*sizeof(person *)); "

Comment: Because you need to allocate memory which is capable of storing `person *` not `person **`.